# How do i make java output number decreasing order

Tags: java

So far this is my code and I need it to output from 66 down to 11. Right now it does 11 upto 66.

```
public class ListNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //define limit
            int limit = 66;

            System.out.println("Printing Even numbers between 1 and " +      limit);

            for(int x=11; x <= limit; x++){
             if(x != 44 && x != 22){
                            System.out.print(x + " ");
                    }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int x = limit; x >= 11; x--)`

Comment: `while(x --> 0) System.out.println(x);`

Comment: Can you clarify your question please, are you looking for just decreasing order? or are you looking for even numbers or?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to start from limit and ends when it reaches 11

```
for(int x = limit; x > 10; x--){
    if(x! = 44 && x != 22){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You start the loop at the upper limit (`66`) and decrements down to the lower limit (`1`). Then you check if they are `even` or `odd` but only output the even numbers.

```
    int lowerLimit = 1;
    int upperLimit = 66;
    System.out.println("Printing Even numbers between " + lowerLimit + " and " + upperLimit);

    for (int x = upperLimit; x >= lowerLimit; x--)
    {
        if ((x & 1) == 0)
        {
            // even
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
        else
        {
            // odd
        }
    }
```

Comment: *If this helped you please upvote and select as the answer :) and if it is wrong downvote me* ;-)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson his question says 66 to 11 but the code says `Printing Even numbers between 1 and " + limit`, so you tell me :/

Comment: @ScaryWombat i don't think i said anything wrong. The question was very unclear considering part of it had `even` numbers in there. But i now have enough reputation to comment so i can get clarification before i post answers =D Hurrah

Comment: @JordanGS Good catch. He didn't mention it anywhere in his question. I never actually read the string.

Comment: @ScaryWombat that's why i added a variable called `lowerLimit` and another called `upperLimit`, set it to whatever you want :)

Comment: Please don't add requests for votes/accepts here - people's voting should be as organic as possible. If you believe that someone has forgotten to do so however, or is not aware of this system, a gentle reminder _in the comments_ is OK. Just not in posts please, it creates editing work.